# How to combine structures with fields of different sizes

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab, so apologies if my language is not very specific.
I have 25 files, one for each subject. All of them are 1x1 struct with 42 fields, but fields have different size and are of different type (e.g. struct, cell, etc) based on the subject.
What I would like to do is to create a big structure where to keep the data of all my subjects together, because I will then need to calculate the EEG grand average for all subjects.

However, I don't know how to create this big structure with all the data of each subject. Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: When you say you want to combine all your data, do you mean you want a single struct with 42*25 fields? Or do you want a single struct with 42 fields where each field is made up by somehow concatenating all 25 files together?

Comment: Thanks for your question. The second option. I would like a single structure with 42 fields, and each field made up concatenating the information of all my 25 subjects.

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenating"? This sounds like a good use of an array of structures: [more here](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/array-of-structures-vs-structures-of-arrays-97327.html).

Comment: I tried to create an array of structures by manually defining each file and then vertically concatenating the structures. But is there a way to automatize this procedure, maybe with a loop?
    
data1 = pop_loadset('filename',A,'filepath',folder);
data2 = pop_loadset('filename',B,'filepath',folder);
data3 = pop_loadset('filename',C,'filepath',folder);
data4 = pop_loadset('filename',D,'filepath',folder);
z = {data1; data2; data3; data4; ........data25};

Comment: The mega-structure is already created in the software you use. For a single file, `pop_loadset` loads a file, store it in the structure EEG. For a second file, the data is again stored in EEG (therefore replacing the first file), but EEG_ALL has both the data. You call them via `data1 = ALLEEG(1)` and `data2 = ALLEEG(2)`. You may ask the EEGLAB community via the mailinglist though, or simply read the corresponding doc.